Excel VBA calling a Function in MSForm from another Function in same MSForm using Run, give error 1004
I have a MSForm with many TextBox fields. I want them to have correct format and correct content so all communication to them goes through getters and setters, preNamed with TBfieldname
Suddenly there occured a situation where data read into the textbox had wrong format and content. I do not want to change my whole structure based on this odd situation, but just call a general function, and if the data is wrong, correct directly to the getters and setters.
  'Initialize it 
    'Add Leader
    If Not CheckForInconsistData("Leader", accounts.Cells(1, 1).Value, _
           accounts.Cells(1, 2).Value, accounts.Cells(1, 3).Value, accounts.Cells(1, 4).Value) Then
      TbLeader = accounts.Cells(1, 1).Value
      ...

Private Function CheckForInconsistData(sCtrlName As String, vCtrl1 As Variant, vCtrl2 As Variant, vCtrl3 As Variant, vCtrl4 As Variant) As Boolean
  If vCtrl1 = "-" And (Not vCtrl2 = "-" Or Not vCtrl3 = "-" Or Not vCtrl4 = "-") Then
    'Clear the fields for member and set it status to changed
    Call SearchAndFillInBoardMember(sCtrlName, 0) 'Member 0 means clear the fields
    Dim sFunctionName As String
    sFunctionName = "UF_TableBoard.HasInconsistTb" & sCtrlName
    Run (sFunctionName, True)
    Run Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & sFunctionName, True
  End If
End Function

'Textbox TbLeader, representing a Variant
Private Property Get TbLeader() As Variant
  TbLeader = txtBoxes(bwiTBLeader).GetValue
End Property
Private Property Let TbLeader(ByVal lNewValue As Variant)
  txtBoxes(bwiTBLeader).SetReference lNewValue
  txtBoxes(bwiTBLeader).SetValue lNewValue
End Property
Public Function HasInconsistTbLeader(ByVal bInconsist As Boolean)
  txtBoxes(bwiTBLeader).InconsistData (bInconsist)
End Function

This function say to the userform that the field has changed even the user had not made any changes in GUI
In my general function I test if inputdata is valid, if so call the correct setter dependent on the name of the textbox. Build up a string 'FunctionName' representing the setter " and then using: Run (FunctionName, parameters)
But when running the function through Run, i got error 1004.
I searched in the database on this issue, but did not found any good solution to the problem
My workbook has of course enabled Macroes, and the functions are public. One of the answers i fount to solve such problems was to put it in a module.
The functions is in a MSForm, i belive I could do the same in a MsForm
Tried:
    Dim sFunctionName As String
    sFunctionName = "UF_TableBoard.Tb" & sCtrlName
    Run (sFunctionName, True)
    Run Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!" & sFunctionName, True

But none of them worked.
Is it problem with the notation or is it something compleatly different?
Is there a better way to think through the solution in general?
Thanks for any help that will solve my problem
Jo-Helge
Tried several ways to use the Run function

Is the procedure to be run a Function, as you said or a Sub? A function usually returns something. Do you need the function to return anything?

In general I use Functions, and return a boolean if it completed without any problem. My  solution printed was not the final solution, but an example of how it was intended to work. I will rewrite the function content to support Boolean return value. The reason why I wanted to use Run was that I didn't have to use wrapper, but just call a function name that I formatted 'on the run' and call this function. All functions have the same Style with equal number of parameters and same type

Then, I am afraid you cannot call a function situated in a user form code module, from ANOTHER WORKBOOK without using such a wrapper. If you create the function on the fly, you can do the same with the wrapper one. Otherwise, you cannot call it from a different workbook...

You did not answer my clarification question, so I will assume that you really need to call a function and use its return...

Having such a function in a user form (UserForm4) (It needs to NOT be Private!):

Public Function Multiplication(x As Long, y As Double) As Double
  Multiplication = x * y
End Function

you can simple call it (from the same workbook) in the next way:
Sub testCallFunctionFromForm() 'it works.
   Dim x As Double
   x = UserForm4.Multiplication(3, 567.47)
   Debug.Print x
End Sub

It will return 1702.41

You can call a function from a different workbookk only if it exists in a standard module. So, you need a function wrapper in such a module, respectively:

Function UFMultiplicationWrapper(a As Long, x As Double) As Double
   UFMultiplicationWrapper = UserForm4.Multiplication(a, x)
End Function


Then activate the above used workbook and call the user form function trough the wrapper function in the next way:

Sub testCallFunctionFromFormOtherWb() 'it works...
   Dim x As Double
   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   x = Application.Run("'" & wb.Name & "'!" & "UFMultiplicationWrapper", 3, 867.47)
   Debug.Print x
End Sub

It will return 2602.41...
Note: If it is not a matter of ActiveWorkbook, using wb.FullName will also work even if the workbook is not open (it opens it...)
So, in order to receive the returned function output the used parenthesis evaluates the run function output. And placing the workbook name (full name) between "'" ... "'" takes care of spaces between words contained in the workbook  name/full name. Otherwise, it will error, the string parameters being split according to existing spaces...
But, if you need to call a Sub from a user form (the same UserForm4 example) you need such a sub in its code module:
Public Sub MyMessage(strMess As String)
   MsgBox strMess
End Sub

and a wrapper Sub as:
Sub UFSubMessageWrapper(x As String)
  UserForm4.MyMessage x
End Sub

in the same workbook with the respective UserForm.
Then, activate the workbook call the sub it as:
Sub callSubFromOtherWBUserForm()
   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & "UFSubMessageWrapper", "Hello!"
End Sub

It will raise a message containing "Hello!"...
As you can see, no need of parenthesis because nothing is to be evaluated...

I'm sorry for late response, but have been out of office until now!

You use Run only when it is to another workbook, and then the code you call  has to be located in a module.

@Jo-Helge Rorvik Something as you say, but not only that... In case of a function call, it needs Application.Run evaluation. You can call a function from a user form without using Run if called from the same workbook. But you cannot do it from a different workbook. So, you need a wrapper macro situated in a standard module, able to call the function and return its output... Did you try applying to your case? Do you really need calling a function? Do you understand the difference between a Function and a Sub?

From this I can conclude that my intention using Run to call a Function in a UserForm not will work. Even that the function I'll wanted to call is within the same workbook. Please answer if my conclusion is wrong and it is possible to use Run

A Sub do not return anything, while a Function return a Value of a specific Type. When you use Run, it use a generic way of calling accessible methods in ActiveWorkbook or any other workbook. It is handled outside of the workbook. while a Call is within the same workbook.

@Jo-Helge Rorvik You can call it from the same workbook! The suggested wrapper function does exactly this. It calls the function from the user form code module... Since you did not use ThisWorkbook and you used ActiveWorkbook I thought that it involves another workbook... The suggested solution works for both cases...

@Jo-Helge Rorvik Should I understand that the above solution did not answer your question?
